# Trying to truncate string after it's called by loop via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, loops, truncate

I have a table which include names, the last name of each entry needs to be truncated ex. Miles Davis becomes Miles D.

I achieve this with the following JS:

```
$('.trunc-name').each(function (d, td) {
    $(td).text($(td).text().replace(/^(\S+)\s+(\S).*/, '$1 $2.'));
});
```

and the `td` class is set to `trunc-name`:

```
<td class="trunc-name"><?php foreach ($resident_name_terms as $object) { echo $object->name; } ?></td>
```

Those table contents (which are actually WP taxonomy terms) are filterable via a select form - the options of which are getting truncated too.

Select:

```
if( $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'resident_name',
    'orderby' => 'name'
     ) ) ) :
     echo '<select name="resident_name_filter"><option value="" selected="selected">' . __( 'All Residents', 'mv' ) . '</option>';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
         echo '<option class="trunc-name" value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; 
     endforeach;
     echo '</select>';
endif;
```

So far everything works fine. The problem is that when I change criteria via a select option for that column (built with AJAX), the newly outputted values are not truncated.

Query Params:

```
$relation = 'AND';
$params = array();
$args['tax_query']['relation'] = $relation;

foreach ( $taxonomies as $tax ) {
    if( isset( $_POST[ $tax . '_filter' ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ $tax . '_filter' ] ) ) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $tax,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST[ $tax . '_filter' ],
        );
    }
};
```

Loop:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <table style="width:100%" id="incident-reports">
        <tr>
            <th>Resident</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
                $resident_name_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'resident_name' );
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td class="trunc-name"><?php foreach ($resident_name_terms as $object) { echo $object->name; } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
endif;
```

Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated!

Comment: When do you execute the truncation code? You need to do it after you update the list dynamically.

Comment: Make sense, thanks! Any insight on how I can do that? I tried placing that JS inside my function that applies the AJAX, to no avail.

Comment: Show what you tried, I think it should work

Comment: I just figured it out wrapping the function in `ajaxComplete()` - fires after any ajax runs. If you want to put that in answer form, I'm happy to accept it as your comment led to the answer.

Comment: That will run after every AJAX call, it seems like overkill. You should just run it in the `success:` function of the call that updates the relevant element.

Comment: Good point, thanks! Feel free to put that in answer form so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the truncate code in the `success:` function after it creates the new elements.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(response) {
        ... // code that adds the new HTML
        $('.trunc-name').each(function (d, td) {
            $(td).text($(td).text().replace(/^(\S+)\s+(\S).*/, '$1 $2.'));
        });
    }
});
```